# Merge Multiple object Values in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have three values in my controller like:

```
 $data['all_video_posts_ByCategory'] = $this->Blogmodel->all_video_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
 $data['all_text_posts_ByCategory'] = $this->Blogmodel->all_text_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
 $data['all_audio_posts_ByCategory'] = $this->Blogmodel->all_audio_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
```

In my view page I have to show all my posts within one foreach loop. So how to merge these three data and send to view page?

Comment: Can paste the output of the $data array

Comment: show your model code because i think you should do this in one query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest making sure your model returns as `$this->db->get()->result_array();`

Then in your controller do the following:

```
$videos = $this->Blogmodel>all_video_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
$texts = $this->Blogmodel->all_text_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
$audio = $this->Blogmodel->all_audio_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);

$data['array'] = array_merge($videos, $texts, $audio);
```

Comment: Thanks Sir.. Also i need to sort these by date . How to do that sir

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing all your data in $data just

```
return $data
```

A better solution will be to divide those vars

```
$data['all_video_posts_ByCategory'] = $this->Blogmodel->all_video_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
$data['all_text_posts_ByCategory'] = $this->Blogmodel->all_text_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
$data['all_audio_posts_ByCategory'] = $this->Blogmodel->all_audio_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
```

change your code ^ to this

```
$videos = $this->Blogmodel>all_video_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
$texts = $this->Blogmodel->all_text_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
$audio = $this->Blogmodel->all_audio_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
```

Then you can return them individually and acces them one by one in your view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same logic then do it with multidimensional array.

> $data['post']['all_video_posts_ByCategory'] = $this->Blogmodel->all_video_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
>   $data[post]['all_text_posts_ByCategory'] = $this->Blogmodel->all_text_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);
>   $data['post']['all_audio_posts_ByCategory'] = $this->Blogmodel->all_audio_posts_ByCategory($cat_id);

In view use below logic

> ```
> foreach($post as $row) {  foreach($row as $innerpost) {print your values;} }
> ```

Why multi dimension array because if future if you want you use your audio, video, and text post separately if you want.

If you want use one foreach loop then you need merge the array first in controller and then you can use.